# joining multiple tables with left join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following query:

```
$products_query = 
  tep_db_query("select op.orders_products_id, op.orders_id, op.products_id, ".
                      "op.products_model, op.products_name, op.products_quantity, ".
                      "p.products_id from " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . " op " .
                  " left join " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p " .
                  " on (op.products_id = p.products_id) where orders_id = '" . 
                  (int)$cuttinglist['orders_id'] . "'");
```

This joins two tables together with the same id. How would I join a 3rd table called:

```
"TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES"
```

with the same id as:

```
"TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS"
```

The ID used is:

```
"orders_products_id"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it easier to read your code (and so you don't need to have so many concats and quotes everywhere you can do a query like this:

```
$sql='
select 
    op.orders_products_id, 
    op.orders_id, op.products_id,
    op.products_model, 
    op.products_name, 
    op.products_quantity,
    p.products_id 
from 
    '.TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS.' op 
        left join '.TABLE_PRODUCTS.' p 
            on op.products_id = p.products_id
        left join '.TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES.' Attrib
            on op.orders_products_id=Attrib.orders_products_id
where 
    orders_id = "' .(int)$cuttinglist['orders_id'] . '"
';
$products_query = tep_db_query($sql);
```

Comment: TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS amd TABLE_PRODUCTS are PHP constants, so you do need those quotes (or replace it some other way).

Answer (score 1):

```
$products_query = 
  tep_db_query("select op.orders_products_id, op.orders_id, op.products_id, ".
                  "op.products_model, op.products_name, op.products_quantity, ".
                  "p.products_id from " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS . " op " .
              " left join " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p " .
              " on (op.products_id = p.products_id) "
              " left join " . TABLE_ORDERS_PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES . " pa " .
              " on (op.products_id = pa.orders_products_id) where orders_id = '" . 
              (int)$cuttinglist['orders_id'] . "'");
```